# Regular expression query

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

I am looking for regular expression that evaluates below.

```
0-9 a-Z A-Z - / '
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C# version of this pattern is:

```
@"[0-9a-zA-Z/'-]"
```

Used in code:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"[0-9a-zA-Z/'-]");
```

or

```
var regex = new Regex(@"[0-9a-z/'-]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Note that the `-` is at the **very end** of the character class (the part in the brackets). For `-` to mean a literal hyphen inside a character class, it must be at the beginning or end of the class (i.e. `[-blah]` or `[blah-]`), or escaped with a backslash: `[ab\-c]` will match `a`, `b`, `c`, or `-`.

Note also the `@` at the beginning of the quoted string. This isn't important for this pattern, but it's a good habit to get into with C# regex. Regular expressions often contain backslashes, and the `@"..."` form will allow you to use backslashes in your pattern without having to escape them.

Answer (score 0):

Use bellow code to validate(Regex patterns) Alphabetic and numbers:

```
String name="123ABCabc";

if(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(name, @"[0-9a-zA-Z_]") == true)
{
  return true;
}
else 
{
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In the case you want to match digits, lower- and higher-case latin characters, "-", "/" and "'" then I would suggest the following:

```
[0-9a-zA-Z-\/\']
```

Comment: And remember to escape the backslash or to use verbatim string literals `@"..."`

Comment: ...or leave the backslashes out.  Neither `/` nor `'` has any special meaning in a regex.  The `-` is probably okay where it is (different flavors have different rules about that), but I would move it to the end anyway, to remove any doubt that it's supposed to match a literal hyphen.